# Is correct to understand the way for preserving elements in matrix by $y=A(2:end,:)A^{-1}x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix such as
$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 2 \\
        -2 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
And it can decompose in to $A=\begin{bmatrix}
        B \\
        -\\
        C
        \end{bmatrix}$ such as
$$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$C=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$B$ is a matrix contains first row of $A$, $C$ is a matrix that includes two last elements of $A$.

Given a vector $x$
$$x=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 \\
        6 \\
        7\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I implement the formula
$$y=CA^{-1}x=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        6 \\
        7\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
I don't know why the above formula can preserve the two last element of vector $x$ (ex:6,7). 
Could you explain to me by mathematic?

Extension: 
What is happen if I extend matrix $C$ as following
$$C_{extend}=\begin{bmatrix}
        C\\
        D
        \end{bmatrix}$$
What is result of $$y_{extend}=C_{extend}A^{-1}x=??$$
This is my understand:
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        B \\
        -\\
        C
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        B \\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$+$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        C\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$.
We have $AA^{-1}x=x$
Then 
$AA^{-1}x=\begin{bmatrix}
        B \\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
A^{-1}x$+$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        C\\
        \end{bmatrix}
A^{-1}x=x$.
Then only consider second term we have
$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        C\\
        \end{bmatrix}
A^{-1}x=\begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        x_2 \\
        x_3\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
e_1^T=[1,0,\cdots,0],\cdots,e_n^T=[0,0,\cdots,1]
$$
Where $e_i^T$ is known as unit vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The effect of multiplying transpose of unit vector from left with a matrix is to get a row of the matrix, and multiplying unit vector from right with a matrix is to get a column of the matrix. This fact can be proved easily. More precisely,
$$
e_i^TA=\alpha_i^T, \hspace{2 mm} \alpha_i^T \hspace{1 mm} \text{is the }i^{th} \text{row of }A
$$
$$
Ae_i=\alpha_i, \hspace{2 mm} \alpha_i \hspace{1 mm} \text{is the }i^{th} \text{column of }A
$$

In your case, 
$$
C=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   e_2^T \\
   e_3^T \\
  \end{array}  \right]A, \hspace{3 mm}  \text{where} \space e_2^T=[0,1,0],e_3^T=[0,0,1]
$$

So 
$$
y=CA^{-1}x=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   e_2^T \\
   e_3^T \\
  \end{array}  \right]AA^{-1}x=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   e_2^T \\
   e_3^T \\
  \end{array}  \right]x=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   e_2^Tx \\
   e_3^Tx \\
  \end{array}  \right]=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   x_2 \\
   x_3 \\
  \end{array}  \right]
$$

For extension of $C$, there is 
$$
y_{ext}=C_{ext}A^{-1}x=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   C \\
   D \\
  \end{array}  \right]A^{-1}x=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   CA^{-1}x \\
   DA^{-1}x \\
  \end{array}  \right]=\left[ \begin{array}{}
   y \\
   DA^{-1}x \\
  \end{array}  \right]
$$

Comment: Nice explanation. How about if I consider extend matrix $C$ as my update. It can use your explanation to prove it

Comment: Thank for your help. How about my explanation. Is it correct?

Comment: Your explanation is right.